# Android Facebook - nearby places

Tags: android, facebook

There is a way to show the nearby places screen of facebook?
(Exactly the screen if you press the CHECK-IN button in facebook app).
It's presents a screen with a list of nearby places.

If there is a url scheme (fb:// ...) to reach that screen - it will be the perfect solution for me.
(I've tried `fb://nearby` it is not exactly the screen that i am looking for)

The second options (The hard way) if there is no simple way like above, is to implement it using facebook SDK i guess...
The final result of what I need is presenting the user his nearby places, and he can click on one and it will check-in there.

Comment: Are you asking if the Facebook Android app does this, or do you want to develop it in your own Android app?

Comment: I would like to open the facebook app and redirect to this screen immediately, via my app.

Comment: Do you also want it to return a place ID to you? In either case, there's no support for what you're asking, but I'm curious what your use case is.

Comment: My use case is just a button in my app, when you click on it, it opens nearby places screen, you choose one and check-in there.  I think that it's a basic feature. (Same act exactly if you click on CHECK-IN button in facebook app).